# In Python 3, can I convert a character such as '1' to an int, such as 1 within a list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Firstly, this is not homework :)
I would like to put this code into a list comprehension but perhaps a comprehension is not the way to go? The equivalent for loop:

```
matrix = [['1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
          ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
          ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0']
         ]
new_matrix = [][]

for i=len(matrix):
   for j in len(matrix[0]):
      new_matrix[i][j] = ord(matrix[i][j])
```

I'm sure it's obvious I'm new to python. I'm looking to find out how things work.

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: Use `int()` to turn {a string that represents a number} into an integer. Use `float()` to make a float instead. You can check if the string represents a number by calling `.isdigit()` on it. Don't use `ord()` for this - `ord()` will just give you the ASCII code of a character.

Comment: also: `new_matrix = [[int(elem) for elem in row] for row in matrix]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify are you suggesting that a for-loop is the best way to handle this and not use a list comprehension?

Comment: Thanks very much. I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Green Cloak Guy: If you make this an answer I will gladly upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
matrix = [['1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
          ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
          ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0']]
          
new_matrix = [[int(char) for char in row] for row in matrix]
print(new_matrix)
```

output:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

**Explaination**

fistly, to convert a string to an int you need the`int()` builtin function

then take a look at this list comprehension:

1. iterate above every `row` and create a new list
2. for every `row` append to the new list each `char` converted to an `int`

when you works with lists the most pythonic (and the usual the optimal) way to do it is to use list comprehension, for more info about them look [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)